# LocationProvider costAllowed

Tags: android, location

When you choose a locationProvider by Criteria you can choose to allowCost or not.
But of which cost we are talking about?
If I choose to don't allow cost I allow the network provider?
Which providers can have a cost?

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that if you allow costs, that the application can/will connect to the internet via 3G to get a location. Otherwise GPS or Wi-Fi will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

The API Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#setCostAllowed%28boolean%29) just says 'incur monetary value'. From that I can only assume data traffic over a celluar connection, i.e Using Assisted GPS or CellID lookup when a WiFi connection isn't available.